# Cohorts analysis

Tags: sql, data-analysis, analysis, retention

Hey guys so im trying to do a cohorts analysis on sql I have hit my head trying to figure out this syntax for a question like : Proportion of users that have played a game the day after installing. Does anyone have an idea of the syntax?

Comment: Do you have any sample data and desired output you can provide?

Comment: If you were like me thinking what the heck is Cohorts analysis... https://clevertap.com/blog/cohort-analysis/

Comment: I would link some data in db-fiddle or similar website  and show desired result in your question. I don't think you'll get much traction on this question without it. (Google "SQL Playground").

Comment: If anyone were to help you on this it would be someone like  https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff - This is the kind of thing he's written books on. And IIRC he's the top SQL guru on SO.

Comment: EdemDuke . . . Your question is just too broad.  It should have sample data, desired results, an appropriate database tag, and an attempt that you have made to solve the problem.